# c# get value list from excel file

Tags: c#, string, excel

I'm working on a dll for Excel file.
In the dll I want to do a method in which the client will enter the row to get the list from, and then enter the column from and to get list.
something like:
public List GetValueList(int inRow, string fromColumn, string toColumn)

The problem is- how can I get do it? in Excel there are columns like "AZX", "AA" and so on... I can't just do "fromColumn++".

Any ideas? I hope I explained myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Cells` member of the `Worksheet` object takes both row and column numbers as integers. So you can do something like this:

```
List<object> GetValueList(Worksheet WS, int inRow, int fromColumn, int toColumn)
{
    List<object> MyList = new List<object>(toColumn - fromColumn + 1);
    for(int i=fromColumn; i<=toColumn; i++)
        MyList.Add(WS.Cells[inRow, i].Value);

    return MyList;
}
```

Note that both fromColumn and toColumn are integers. If you need to convert from an alphabetic column number (like BD or AFH), simply use `WS.Range("BD" + "1").Column`, replacing "BD" with the actual column number you have.

Comment: I think "WorkSheet" is a typo. It should be "Worksheet"

Comment: @JayBrown: Yep Fixed. Thx.